# What is a word that means someone who is involved in the arts without implying a specific type of art?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word that encompasses artist, poets, architects, dancers, musicians?

The correct word to use is surely "Artist" but in my context that word is confusing as it connotes someone involved in the visual arts making it unacceptable for me.

Is there a word that covers creative pursuits?

Comment: Perhaps _creator_?

Comment: Yes, the word 'artist' ostensibly means any kind of art: writers, painters, musicians, etc. But without any context it usually does mean a painter. As to an obvious word that is the hypernym of all those examples without the default connotations that 'artist' has... we'll see what people come up with.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"**involved** in the arts"*? For example, would this include people with no creative talent or aspirations, who donate time and/or money to theatres, for example? What about those who just like to *appreciate* art (go to exhibitions, etc.)?

Comment: @FumbleFingers sorry I mean people who directly create the art

Comment: You might be able to use "*artists of every sort*" [not just painters] as a noun phrase.

Comment: Does the curator of an art museum or the administrator of an art scholarship fall under your umbrella of someone involved in the arts?

Comment: It wouldn't, sorry for being unclear. I'm really just looking for a synonym of the word artist without the connotations.

Comment: @Mitch It is sad to learn that the word "artist" may have connotations **in the absence of context** that exclude some forms of art :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Artist*** would be the first choice; however, as it doesn't work for your context, another single word option is ***executant***. It is not a very common word and it is usually used for a musical performer. *Executant artist* may be used as well.

> ***noun*** ~ An artist or musician:
>
> *she could play, though not an advanced executant*
>
> ***adjective*** ~ Relating to artistic creation or the performance of music:
>
> *music is both an art and an executant skill*
>
> [*oxforddictionaries*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/executant)

***Creator*** is not a bad idea also, though it still depends on the context; so why don't we go with an ***art-creator***? It still means an artist but puts the emphasis on creation and makes it clear that it is about art also.

The term *art-creator* wasn't prevalent throughout the history per *[Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=art-creator&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cart%20-%20creator%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cart%20-%20creator%3B%2Cc0)* but the term was used to refer to various types of artists, such as Leonardo da Vinci and the composer Franz Schubert.

Here are some usages with the terms "creator" and "art-creator" from Google Books (I've compared past and contemporary usages and included some relevant excerpts; though there are usages with religious connotations as well which I've excluded):

> As Wladyslaw Tatarkiewicz sums up this point: "Only in the nineteenth century did the
> term 'creator' enter the language of art. But it then became the *exclusive* property (in the human world) of art: creator became a synonym for artist. New expressions, formerly superfluous, were formed, such as the adjective 'creative' and the noun 'creativity'; these were used exclusively in reference to artists and their labor." Wladyslaw Tatarkiewicz, *A History of Six Ideas: An Essay in Aesthetics*, trans. Christopher Kasparek (The Hague: Martinus Nijhoff, 1980), 251.
>
> <sup>*Gadamer and the Legacy of German Idealism* by Kristin Gjesdal</sup>

---

> Briefly considered, it would appear that the artist, by which is meant the art-creator, is not the product of any known cause; that he visits unbidden and unaccounted for the haunts of men; but, on the other hand, the art-lovers are largely the product of favoring or unfavoring influences of widely different education, leisure to observe, capacity to valne, and desire to possess the products of artistic genius.
>
> <sup>*Evolution in Science, Philosophy and Art: Popular Lectures and Discussions Before the Brooklyn Ethical Association* by Brooklyn Ethical Association</sup>

---

> He suggests that art is an adaptation that serves to draw attention to the art-creator and that promotes positive social interaction. This accounts both for art's origins and for its current function.
>
> <sup>*The Artful Species: Aesthetics, Art, and Evolution*
> by Stephen Davies</sup>

---

Comment: It's a pretty antiquated term, and using it for anyone except *performing musicians* (as opposed to *composers*) would be rather unlikely.

Comment: @Fumble: Thanks for the emphasis. OP was asking for a single word other than artist so this word came to my mind. Though, artist or other phrases can be used depending on how you form the sentence.

Comment: That Ngram doesn't show that the usage has _diminished_; it shows the term was _never very prevalent_. (Notice the ultra-small values on the Y-axis, and then compare it to [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=art+creator%2Can+artist%2Cthe+artist&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3).) Also, if the O.P. is concerned that people may need to think twice before associating the word _artist_ with _musician_ or _performing artist_, I don't see how the word _executant_ would help much; I think _artist_ would probably be better. It's still a cool word, though.

Comment: @J.R. Except in the 1860s. Wow, those were the days! :-)

Comment: @Mark - Ah, the 1860s; there are about [12 instances](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22art%20creator%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1860,cd_max:1870) from that decade. Some are praises to God ("Thou art creator of heaven and earth"); some are self-help ("Thou art creator of thy own happiness"); while some do use it in the executant context ("He was truly an art-lover, and should never have been an art-creator"). Incidentally, _art creator_ **is** a valid option;  I'm simply offering a cautionary word about reading too much into Ngrams without further investigation and analysis.

Comment: We're on the same page. It's hard to look up anything in Ngrams without finding cross-listings into some other context. The word _lamb_, for example, could refer to an animal, a tasty dish, the Lamb of God, or a writer named Wally. A _calf_ can be a cow, whale, or muscle. I never doubted the legitimacy of _art-creator_; even if I had, you've cited enough sources to back your assertion. I appreciate the research.

Answer (score 1):

We would call them a **creative type**.

> Jane is really a creative type.  She always seems to be producing a short film, painting, or drawing!

It describes people with an artistic bend to them of any type.

Otherwise, **artist** is still appropriate to describe anyone who creates art of any type.

Comment: Hmm I like this. "Creative artist" might be suitable, adding the word creative there implies that it should not be thought of as just a painter.

Comment: @Harry - You already had creative and artist in your post.  Also an architect isn't a creative artist.  That is really the profession that is hard to fit with the others.

Comment: @RyeBread why isn't an architect a creative artist?  Yes they have to conform to building codes, etc. but you can't say someone like [I.M. Pei](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/I._M._Pei) wasn't a creative artist.

Comment: Indeed, art history classes generally include architecture along with visual arts.

Comment: Just "creative" (noun) would also work.

Comment: “We”? Please take personal responsibility for your opinions. I certainly would not use an expression involving the word “type” in this context.